# How can I refresh TableViewCell data with Refresh Control

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to load data into a `UITableViewCell` whenever the refresh control is activated. My code successfully retrieves the data and I can verify this with `NSLog`, but the ViewCell does not update with the new data when Refresh Control ends. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Below is MyViewController.m file:

```
#define JSON_URL @"https://website.com"
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Object.h"
#import "MyViewCell.h"
@interface MyViewController ()


@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *objectHolderArray;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:JSON_URL];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in dataDictionary) {
    Object *currenHotel = [[Object alloc]Station:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"station"] Status:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"status"]];
    [self.objectHolderArray addObject:currenHotel];
}
[super viewDidLoad];

//to add the UIRefreshControl to UIView
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Please Wait..."]; //to give the attributedTitle
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}



- (IBAction)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self viewDidLoad];
    [sender endRefreshing];
}




#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.objectHolderArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MartaViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
Object *currentHotel = [self.objectHolderArray
                             objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.lblStation.text = currentHotel.station;
cell.lblStatus.text = currentHotel.status;
return cell;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)objectHolderArray{
if(!_objectHolderArray) _objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
return _objectHolderArray;
}


@end
```

Comment: are you reloading table after retrieving data?

Comment: Don't call viewDidLoad, only system should call it. Call tableView.reloadData instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload your data. Implement Refreshcontroll like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(update)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.startScreenView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void) update {
     [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
     [yourTableView reloadData];
     [refreshControl endRefreshing];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually modify, nor reload the table view and its data in any way in the refresh function. You should update the data source of your table view and then call `[tableView reloadData];` after the update.